# How to filter R dataset by multiple partial match strings, similar to SQL % wildcard?

Tags: r, string, wildcard

I have a dataset with with a field of interest and a list of strings (several hundred of them).

What I want to do is, for each line of the data, to check if the field has any of the partials strings in it.

Essentially, I want to replicate the SQL % wildcard. So, if for example a value is "Game123" and one of my strings is "Ga" I want that to be a match. (But I don't want "OGame" to match "Ga").

I'm hoping to write some statement like this:

```
df%>%
filter(My_Field contains any one of List_Of_Strings)
```

How do I fill in that filter statement?

I tried to use the %in% operator but couldn't make it work. I know how to use substrings to check against a single string, but I have a long list of them and need to check all of them.

[R filter rows based on multiple partial strings applied to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215672/r-filter-rows-based-on-multiple-partial-strings-applied-to-multiple-columns): This post is similar to what I'm trying to do, but my list of substrings is 400 plus, so I can't write it all out manually in a grepl statement (I think?)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the problem you're facing is this:

You have a list of what could be called key words (what you call "a list of strings") and a vector/column with text (what you call "a field of interest") and your goal is to filter the vector/column on whether or not any of the key words is present. If that's correct the solution might be this:

**Data**:

a. List of key words:

```
keys <- c("how", "why", "what")
```

b. Dataframe with a vector/column of text:

```
df <- data.frame(
  text = c("Hi there", "How are you?", "I'm fine.", "So how's work?", "Ah kinda stressful.", "Why?", "Well you know")
)
```

**Solution**:

To filter `df` on `keys` in `text` you need to convert `keys` into a regex alternation pattern (by collapsing the strings with `|`). Depending on *your* `keys` it may be useful or even necessary to also include word `\\b`oundary markers (in case the `keys` values need to match as such, but not occurring inside other words). And finally, if there may be an issue with lower- or upper-case, we can use the case-insensitive flag `(?i)`:

```
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(text, str_c("(?i)\\b(", str_c(keys, collapse = "|"), ")\\b")))
            text
1   How are you?
2 So how's work?
3           Why?
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no particular dataset or reproductible example, I can think of a way to implement it with two `apply` functions and a smart use of regex.  Remember that the regex operator `^` matches only if the following expression shows up in its beginning.

```
library(dplyr)

MyField <- c("OGame","Game123","Duck","Dugame","Aldubame")

df <- data.frame(MyField)

ListOfStrings <- c("^Ga","^Du") #Notice the use of ^ here

match_s <- function(patterns,entry){
  lapply(patterns,grepl,x = entry) %>% unlist() %>% any()
}

df$match_string <- lapply(df$MyField, match_s, pat = ListOfStrings)

df %>% filter(match_string == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr` (using `stringr` for `words` and `sentences` as examples) and `grepl` in conjunction with `\\b` to get the word boundary match at the beginning.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(22)

tibble(sentences) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(sapply(words[sample(length(words), 10)], function(x) 
    grepl(paste0("\\b", x), sentences)))) %>% 
  ungroup()
# A tibble: 32 × 1
   sentences                                    
   <chr>                                        
 1 It's easy to tell the depth of a well.       
 2 Kick the ball straight and follow through.   
 3 A king ruled the state in the early days.    
 4 March the soldiers past the next hill.       
 5 The dune rose from the edge of the water.    
 6 The grass curled around the fence post.      
 7 Cats and Dogs each hate the other.           
 8 The harder he tried the less he got done.    
 9 He knew the skill of the great young actress.
10 The club rented the rink for the fifth night.
# … with 22 more rows
```